# The eclipse application icon is huge in Unity's dash

Tags: unity, icons, unity-dash

I have a problem with the manual installation of Eclipse Juno.
After unpacking the tarball to `/opt`, adding a symlink from `/usr/local/bin` and adding the following to a new file `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse
GenericName=Integrated Development Application
Comment=Eclipse Juno
Exec=/usr/local/bin/eclipse
TryExec=/usr/local/bin/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

I still get this weird behavior from the dash:

[image: Huge icon in Unity dash]

Eclipse runs just fine and the icon is clickable but as you can see the size is a bit off. How can i fix this? Shouldn't Unity automatically scale the icon?

Comment: Useful Info: This problem exists in Ubuntu 12.10 only. It is working fine in Ubuntu 12.04 or lesser.

Answer (score 26):

- Create a link to ecplise icon.xpm in your share folder:

> ln -s /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm ~/.local/share/icons/eclipse4.xpm

for your user only or

> sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm /usr/share/icons/eclipse4.xpm

for all users

- In your `eclipse.desktop` file (in `~/.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`), replace **Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm** by **Icon=eclipse4**. You don't need to add the `.xpm` suffix.

If necessary, also update `Icon[en_US]` line with the same value.

The file `eclipse.desktop` may have a different name depending on the tool you used to create it.

Edit: Improve answer thanks to Pius, QD. and iAm comments

Comment: That's the answer. I would only add that you don't have to copy the file but can rather make a soft link like `QD.` mentioned below. + If you used Main Menu application to create the .desktop file, you can find it in `~/.local/share/applications`. On my machine it was called `alacarte-made.desktop` so be aware that it's name has nothing to do with the application launched.

Comment: Actually, the best way is to put eclipse4.xpm into /usr/share/icons folder, because using ~/.local/* location works for a single user only.

Answer (score 11):

@Tawane
I add symlink into  ~/.local/share/icons/ which maybe makes it more easy:

```
ln -s /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm ~/.local/share/icons/eclipse.xpm
```

Answer (score 10):

this may help you...

[image]

you can save image and change icon to this.

I scaled image icon.xpm size to 48 x 48 pixel which is in eclipse application

It looks well:

[image]

---

48x48 may look a little blurry on higher (or even medium) resolution. You may use 512x512 (even though it's a little bit an overkill) to ensure your system resizes it to whatever is used. PNGs are resized properly, so you can always supply it with a bigger image than actually displayed.

512x512 icon version can be found here: [Eclipse icon](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/images/icon.png)

The image is taken from Eclipse help page: [Eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fplatform_whatsnew.html)

Answer (score 3):

It seems Unity cannot resize xpm files correctly.

As a workaround, you can convert your icon to png.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
convert /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm /opt/eclipse/icon.png
```

Don't forget to update your .desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but solved this buy copying `icon.xpm` to `/usr/share/pixmaps` and referencing the icon in that folder.

Comment: And what version of Ubuntu you was using? When you say *referencing the icon in that folder*, What folder and how did you reference the icon? Please, edit your answer adding the requested information.

Answer (score -1):

The icon in the eclipse directory (eclipse.xpm) has a size of 256x256. Replace it with a smaller one (48x48 works for me).

Comment: I believe this started with Ubuntu 12.10, before 12.10 xpm icons were resized properly.

Comment: Oh. I first saw this after upgrading to 12.10 and eclipse Juno and thought perhaps it was because of the new eclipse version. I will check of the problem still persists (after all the updates that came in the meantime). If it does, I will file a bug against Ubuntu 12.10.